# Virtualbox error in loading guest additions

Tags: ubuntu, webserver, virtualbox

I have Ubuntu Server installed in Virtualbox under a Windows 7 host that I use as my primary web dev setup. I just came in on Monday morning, after having the computer off all weekend, to turn on my VM to find this error:

> VBoxService: error: VbglR3Init failed with rc=VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

I attempted to do `sudo /etc/init.d/virtualbox-guest-utils` start but that just reproduced the error message. I attempted to unmount and remount the guest additions CD (not that it should make any difference) and I've update my server vm. I'm still at a loss; Google searches are not pulling anything relevant/recent. Anyone run into this lately?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I've reinstalled virtualbox-guest-utils, reboot the system and it works again.

Good luck!